# Continuous spectrum is a subset of point spectrum

Tags: operator-theory, spectral-theory

I have to prove that the continuous spectrum $\sigma_c(T)$ is a subset of the point spectrum $\sigma_p(T)$.

I started off by supposing that there is some spectral value $\lambda$ such that $\lambda \notin \sigma_p(T)$.

Then, this would imply that $(T-\lambda I)$ is invertible.

How can i proceed further to show that  $(T-\lambda I)$ is not bounded so that $\lambda$ is also not in $\sigma_c(T)$, thus proving that,$\sigma_c(T) \subset \sigma_p(T)$  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true !! to convince you, take $T$ the unilateral shift so :
$$
\sigma(T)=\bar{\mathbb{D}}\\
\sigma_p(T)=\mathbb{D}\\
\sigma_c(T)=\mathbb{T}
$$
 [proof](http://www.math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/fun/notes_2012-13/06b_examples_spectra.pdf) page 6-7.